# How to merge two datatables in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have two datatables as follows

**Table1**

```
--------------------------------
Id     | SrNo    | Skill  | Desc
-----------------------------
1      |  1.     | Social    --
2      |  1.1    | Emotional --
3      |  1.2    | Teaching  --
4      |  2.1    | Values    --
5      |  2.2    | Attitude  --
```

**Table2**

```
------------------
Grade   | Remarks
-------------------
A       | --
B       | --
C       | --
```

**Expected result**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Id     | SrNo    | Skill  |   Desc   | Grade   | Remarks
--------------------------------------------------------
1      |   1.    |   Social    |  --    |   A     |     --
2      |   1.1   |   Emotional |  --    |   B     |     --
3      |   1.2   |  Teaching   | --     |  C      |    --
4      |   2.1   |   Values    |  --    |   --    |     --
5      |   2.2   |   Attitude  |  --    |   --    |     --
```

How can i achieve this in c#. If anybody knows this data table operation please share..

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'data table' in an OOP language like C#. This is DB stuff. So what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: There is a DataTable object in C#

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no common column in both table... Please further explain your query

Answer (score 1):

You don't have relationship with table1 and table 2 other than row number.

If your program delete row from table1 then how you going to merge those two tables without relationship?

I think you better start by adding relationship first. If you have primary key ID in table1 and you can add ID column in Table 2 with the relevant ID.

Then you can use `DataTable.Merge` method directly

```
static DataTable GetTable2()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    var colm= table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {colm };
    table.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add( 2, "B2");
    return table;
}


static DataTable GetTable1()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    var colm= table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {colm };
    table.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(1, "A1");
    table.Rows.Add( 2, "A2");
    return table;
}

var tbl = GetTable1();
tbl.Merge(GetTable2());
```

Result :

```
ID  A   B
1   A1  null
2   A2  B2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Merge` Method

The Merge method is used to merge two DataTable objects that have largely similar schemas. A merge is typically used on a client application to incorporate the latest changes from a data source into an existing DataTable. This allows the client application to have a refreshed DataTable with the latest data from the data source.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Eg:**

```
     DataColumn col; 
      DataTable table1 = new DataTable(); 
      table1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
      col = table1.Columns.Add("slot_id") 
       }; 
      col.DataType = typeof(int); 
      col.Unique = true; 
      col = table1.Columns.Add("appointment_time"); 
      col = table1.Columns.Add("patient_name"); 
      col = table1.Columns.Add("patient_doctor"); 

      table1.Rows.Add(1, "0900", "George Michael"); 

      DataTable table2 = new DataTable(); 
      table2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
      col = table2.Columns.Add("slot_id") 
       }; 
      col.DataType = typeof(int); 
      col.Unique = true; 
     col = table2.Columns.Add("appointment_time"); 

      table2.Rows.Add(1, "0900"); 
      table2.Rows.Add(2, "1000"); 
      table2.Rows.Add(3, "1100"); 
      table2.Rows.Add(4, "1200"); 

     DataTable merged = new DataTable(); 
    merged.Merge(table1); 
    merged.Merge(table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DataColumn col;
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            table1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
                  col = table1.Columns.Add("Id")
       };
            col.Unique = true;
            col = table1.Columns.Add("SrNo");
            col = table1.Columns.Add("Skill");
            col = table1.Columns.Add("Desc");

            table1.Rows.Add(1, "1.", "Social","--");
            table1.Rows.Add(2, "1.1", "Emotional", "--");
            table1.Rows.Add(3, "1.2", "Teaching ", "--");
            table1.Rows.Add(4, "2.1", "Values", "--");
            table1.Rows.Add(5, "2.2", "Attitude", "--");


            DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
            table2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
      col = table2.Columns.Add("Id") 
       };
            col.Unique = true;
            col = table2.Columns.Add("Grade");
            col = table2.Columns.Add("Remarks");
            table2.Rows.Add(1,"A","--");
            table2.Rows.Add(2,"B","--");
            table2.Rows.Add(3,"C","--");

            table1.Merge(table2);
```